# Difference between OpenPGP symmetric encryption and AES-256?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, asymmetric, openpgp

I would like to understand the difference between:
OpenPGP **symmetric** encryption 
and 
AES-256 using Winzip/7-zip?

I mean if you encrypt a file with an OpenPGP program like GnuPG, using AES-256 symmetric encryption. And do the same with Winzip/7-zip using AES-256. What is the difference?

[I am not asking about the **asymmetric** encryption in OpenPGP with public-private keys]

Thanks.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136667/can-i-render-public-key-cryptography-quantum-resistant-if-i-treat-even-the-publi one way to make pgp quantum safe like aes-256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenPGP is a standard defining a message format. That message format is fairly complex, but in short, it contains:

- Which algorithm it's using, if any
- Any required parameters for that algorithm (e.g. nonces)
- The (encrypted) message body
- Some other metadata which isn't relevant here

OpenPGP is, notably, *not* an encryption algorithm. It *can use* encryption (and that's its whole raison d'être, so it normally does) but the algorithm it uses is variable.

AES-256, on the other hand, is a specific *algorithm*. It takes as input a secret key and a message, and it encrypts that key with that message.

AES-256 is one of the many encryption algorithms that the OpenPGP standard supports.

Encrypting something with AES-256 and the same key with OpenPGP is going to lead to the same ciphertext (encrypted text) as using any other software. However, there are two things to note:

1. Bad implementations of AES do exist, and [can be exploited](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf), depending on context. Bad usages also exist; for example, the AES *mode* can be any number of things -- ECB, CBC, GCM -- and picking the wrong one could break your security.
2. Because they're in different formats, the *files* produced by telling 7zip to encrypt a zipfile versus telling OpenPGP to encrypt a message will likely be different. However, this has nothing to do with their implementation of AES-256; as long as it's not broken, it'll still produce the same ciphertext. It's just represented differently.